# Grails test JMS messaging

Tags: testing, grails, jms, integration-testing, message-queue

I've got a JMS messaging system implemented with two queues. One is used as a standard queue second is an error queue.

This system was implemented to handle database concurrency in my application. Basically, there are users and users have assets. One user can interact with another user and as a result of this interaction their assets can change. One user can interact with single user at once, so they cannot start another interaction before the first one finishes. However, one user can be in interaction with other users multiple times [as long as they started the interaction].

What I did was: crated an "interaction registry" in redis, where I store the ID of users who begin an interaction. During interaction I gather all changes that should be made to the second user's assets, and after interaction is finished I send those changes to the queue [user who has started the interaction is saved within the original transaction]. After the interaction is finished I clear the ID from registry in redis.

Listener of my queue will receive a message with information about changes to the user that need to be done. Listener will get all objects which require a change from the database and update it. Listener will check before each update if there is an interaction started by the user being updated. If there is - listener will rollback the transaction and put the message back on the queue. However, if there's something else wrong, message will be put on to the error queue and will be retried several times before it is logged and marked as failed. Phew.

Now I'm at the point where I need to create a proper integration test, so that I make sure no future changes will screw this up.

Positive testing is easy, unfortunately I have to test scenarios, where during updates there's an OptimisticLockFailureException, my own UserInteractingException & some other exceptions [catch (Exception e) that is].

I can simulate my UserInteractingException by creating a payload with hundreds of objects to be updated by the listener and changing one of it in the test. Same thing with OptimisticLockFailureException. But I have no idea how to simulate something else [I can't even think of what could it be].

Also, this testing scenario based on a fluke [well, chance that presented scenario will not trigger an error is very low] is not something I like. I would like to have something more concrete.

Is there any other, good, way to test this scenarios?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as I described in the original question and it seems to work fine. 
Any delays I can test with camel.